# PHP/Javascript, Real Filename from Rewritten URL

Tags: php, javascript

I have a Javascript bookmarklet that POSTs to a PHP script, and I need PHP to know the filename of the page that the bookmarklet is POSTing from. I'll be using that filename with `file_put_contents()`, so I need it to be a real file.

The PHP will also be running on the same server as the page being POSTed from.

### **For example:**

- `script.php` is placed in the root of an arbitrary server (`http://site.com/`)
- The operator browses to an arbitrary page on the server (`http://site.com/foo/bar/baz`) before executing the bookmarklet.
- The bookmarklet sends some data to `http://site.com/script.php`.
- `script.php` now needs to make some modifications to the file corresponding to `http://site.com/foo/bar/baz`, but can't resolve the URL to a filename.

---

There's `location.href` in Javascript and `$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ]` in PHP, but in the case of a rewritten URL (via `mod_rewrite` or whatever) these won't contain the real filename.

**Is there any way to find the real filename of a URL in PHP or Javascript?**

Comment: `__FILE__` will give you the full path to the current file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's location.href in Javascript and $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] in
>   PHP, but in the case of a rewritten URL (via mod_rewrite or whatever)
>   these won't contain the real filename.
>
> Is there any way to find the real filename of a URL in PHP or
>   Javascript?

In Javascript: Client side Javascript has no idea about server side code unless the server passes that information to the client. Short answer: not unless you make it possible.

In PHP: I think that `realpath` will translate a URL to a physical file on the local drive (in ASP it is Server.MapPath), BUT, I don't know if that will work for rewritten URLs. I very much doubt it. If I am correct that it will not, then there could possibly be a related function specific to whatever framework you are using, if one is being used. If you are simply using mod_rewrite or similar without a framework, then you would have to code up your own function which knows how to translate from the virtual path to a real one.

Comment: After looking into this more today, I think a generic solution may not exist (`realpath()` only resolves filesystem links, as you say). I'll probably implement some kind of URL conversion for specific setups, as per this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` because the client may choose not to send it, and this seems to be an essential bit of data.

In JavaScript you can only know the URL as it is displayed to the user (via `document.location.href`). If you want to know the filepath of the php script that handles that URL, just have PHP output the filepath somewhere on the page (in JS source) so JS can pick it up and pass it on.

Comment: Thanks Frits, but modifying each page to output its filename isn't really feasible, I'll add a use case to my original question, hopefully that will clarify. :)

Comment: _"So it needs to be a real filename"_, the client can send anything! This is not a safe way to program, you need to rethink what you're doing.

Comment: This isn't really on-topic, but it's a developer tool protected with a passcode. Still, if there's a way to accomplish this without `$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ]`, I'm all for it.